# OpenGL ES 2.0 - Create Bitmap on runtime, use as texture - with transparency

Tags: java, android, bitmap, opengl-es-2.0, transparency

Currently I am working on dynamic textures (i.e. created on runtime) with transparency. My current creation fo the bitmaps looks as follows:

```
b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
final Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
c.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
c.save();
c.translate(paddingLeft, paddingTop);
view.draw(c);
c.restore();
```

Since I am creating a view, which I need as a Bitmap, and then use it as a texture for a plane. This works just fine, I am receiving a bitmap. If I add it into an ImageView and put it on top of my layout, it's also transparent, as far as I can see.

I'm using  `getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);` in my `GLSurfaceView`, as well as `setEGLConfigChooser(8,8,8,8,16,0);`.

The generation of the texture looks like this:

```
GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0]);
// GLES20 tex parameters here as well... (min/mag filter)
GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, bmp, 0);
```

In the fragment shader, I am - for testing purposes - simply applying

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate);
```

So no lights, just taking the texture's color.

But it's not transparent, it has a black border - since I'm creating the bitmap as a power-of-two. That means, if my view's size is e.g. 300x300, the texture will be 512x512, with a transparent border - which is drawn as black in OpenGL ES 2.0.

In my renderer, I am enabling blending as follows:

```
GLES20.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
GLES20.glCullFace(GLES20.GL_BACK);
GLES20.glDepthFunc(GLES20.GL_LEQUAL);
```

But I am not sure, if this is the right blender-function.

So in the end, transparency is disregarded, and shown as black.

Any ideas what I could be missing/doing wrong? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're doing correctly, it sounds like the problem isn't really the texturing. It's the padding you add to round up to a power-of-two that is not transparent.

I initially thought you weren't clearing the entire bitmap, but the `c.DrawColor()` call you have *should* take care of that. Just to be sure, you could try the following immediately after creating the bitmap instead, and see if it makes a difference:

```
b.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

The other approach I can think of is cleaner and nicer: During rendering, don't use the part of the texture you added for padding the size. You can do that by adjusting the texture coordinates to only sample the part of the texture that contains your view. Using the sizes from your example (300x300 view drawn into 512x512 texture), the range of the texture coordinates you use for rendering should then be `0.0f` to `300.0f / 512.0f` in each direction, instead of the usual `0.0f` to `1.0f`.

The blend function you use looks fine.

Comment: That's correct, it's the padding which is not perceived as transparent from OpenGL apparently. I've already tried several approaches to make the Bitmap transparent, but none worked, so I'll try changing the texture coordinates next! Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Works! Simply calculate the percentage-offset (0..1), update texture buffer, add appropriate scaling and no need for transparency anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Loading alpha textures from the Android Bitmap class to OpenGL ES does not really work correctly because Bitmap pre-multiplies the alpha and OpenGL ES assumes non-premultiplied format.  You will see this problem when you do more blending. It is possible to reverse the pre-multiply in your shader code or avoid using the Bitmap class when loading textures for OpenGL ES.  There is more on this [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-1).